Error with function to display a word on a canvas block
The code not working as expected
this function has been flagged:
    function launchWord() {
    fetch('/word')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(word => {
            const x = Math.random() * (canvas.width - 100);
            const y = Math.random() * (canvas.height - 30);
            const direction = getRandomDirection();
            const bgColor = getRandomColor();
            const textColor = getContrastingColor(bgColor);

            const bouncingWord = new BouncingWord(word, x, y, direction.dx, direction.dy, bgColor, textColor);
            words.push(bouncingWord);
        });
}

This occurs on the client side of the code.
The original call on the server side is here;
    app.get('/word', (req, res) => {
    const word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    res.json({ word });
  });

  app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${PORT}`));
}

The code is supposed to fetch and display a random word but is displaying an error code instead
I am pretty sure the problem lies with how this is called fetch('/word') but I do not know how to make the code work.
This is the console output:
script.js:77 
 GET http://127.0.0.1:5501/word 404 (Not Found)
launchWord  @   script.js:77
(anonymous) @   script.js:105

Text should be displayed where the error codes appear. This is what the output looks like canvas boxes with error codes instead of words

what is these backward slashes in .then(response =\> response.text()) .then(word =\> { ?

That was a mistake that happened during copying. Fixed that now

Is it possible you're trying to call the back end using the port for the front end? eg, is http://127.0.0.1:5501 actually where the front end is running and the server is on another port such as 3000 or 3001
